# Eclipse java file not found until edited and saved

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following file structure in my eclipse workspace

- core

  - src

    - com.mygame.game (package)

      - Ability.java
      - Game.java
      - ...
      - Allies-Green.java

Ability.java and Game.java were created using the 'right-click on package->New->Class' method. Allies-Green.java, however, was created using the 'right-click on package->New->File' method. Each time I load my workspace, all code that references Allies-Green.java is marked as an error. If I open Allies-Green.java though, and edit one character and resave it, the problem goes away. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Here is Allies-Green.java relevant code for reference:

```
package com.mygame.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import ...


//only class in file
class AllyGreen extends Ally {

    ...
}
```

Comment: If you try to run this code then do you face any issue?

Comment: I don't think this problem is your code. Eclipse have `.project` file to store information about created project. Maybe you need to modify this file.

Comment: Have you tried `Project > Clean`?

Comment: I have tried creating similar sample code and it ran successfully. I am also getting some red lines but it won't hamper your code. So go ahead and continue your coding.
But so as to activate intelisense (like auto import, auto suggestions after dot operator) it would be better to create another class with diff name using New -> Class, copy content of Allies-Green.java, delete old Allies-Green.java and rename new class to Allies-Green.java. 

I hope this helps